# Angular JS rendering a string as an html with trustasHtml shows error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, render

I have a legacy application which have a ui field that shows a customized text.The customized text now will need to render links as well, so i changed the text rendering to bind it as html so that if there are any anchor tags in the html, they get rendered as Links in the ui. But for some reason it does not work for me.

```
$scope.setActiveTab = function(newTab) {
    $scope.activeTab = newTab;
    $scope.activeTexts = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.tabMap[newTab]);
}
```

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="activeText in activeTexts">
    <div class="col--3"style="word-wrap : break-word"
         ng-bind-html="activeText.customText">
    </div>
</div>
```

When the above code is used , i get the following error in the console for some reason.I'm new to angularJs and i read through the documentation but was unable to find the cause.

> angular.js:11592 Error: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html

Comment: what do you have in $scope.tabMap[newTab] ?

Comment: The ajax calls return the data from server, which was then set to this scope variable after sorting the data to be viewed according to the tab.

Comment: As you are applying `ng-repeat` to `$scope.activeTexts`, it should be an array.Check the values of this array. You may need to apply `$sce.trustAsHtml` to each of them.

Comment: @HarshadYou are right , that was the issue , the function expects a string as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that , the  $sce.trustAsHtml() will only work with string. I was trying to apply it to an array of data, when the function expected a string argument.I was able to overcome this by iterating over the data and applying sanitize to every object in the array.Below code fixed it for me :

```
$scope.setActiveTab = function(newTab) {
    $scope.activeTab = newTab;

    for (var i=0; i < $scope.activeTexts.length; i++) {
        $scope.activeTexts[i].customText = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.activeTexts[i].customText);
    }
}
```